# Giving proper width issue

Tags: html, css

I am trying to reduce the width and height of my image for small devices but without any success... Why am I loosing half of the image when I try to change the width for ex. ? Lets say I want to make it 50x100 or 70x60, how I can keep the whole image structure but without slicing it?
Here is example of my code

```css
.logo { width: 100px; height: 100px; margin: 39px 0 0 3px; }
.logo a { display: block; height: 100%; background: url(https://i.downloadatoz.com/download/icon2/e/9/1/58ad7b4d1acbb54cd382e152b3a6619e.jpg) no-repeat 0 0; font-size: 0; line-height: 0; font-style: normal; overflow: hidden; text-indent: -100%; }
```

```html
<div class="logo">
  <a href="#">Book Store</a>
</div>
```

Comment: use background-size: contain;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code..
Instead of specifying width and height, use **background-size** attribute.

```css
.logo { width: 100px; height: 100px; margin: 39px 0 0 3px; }
.logo a { display: block; height: 100%; background: url(https://i.downloadatoz.com/download/icon2/e/9/1/58ad7b4d1acbb54cd382e152b3a6619e.jpg) no-repeat 0 0; font-size: 0; line-height: 0; font-style: normal; overflow: hidden; text-indent: -100%;
background-size:50px 50px;}
```

```html
<div class="logo">
  <a href="#">Book Store</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

While the snippet you provided doesn't really help to show us the problem, I think you're looking for the CSS property `background-size: contain`.

Documentation here (about a quarter of the way down the page): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size

Example here: http://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_background-size&preval=contain